# SQL _ wildcard not working as expected. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

so i have this query

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
```

from there I wanted to grab all data in col1 that have exactly 5 characters and start with 15

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where col1 like '15___' -- underscore 3 times
```

Now col1 is a nvarchar(192) and there are data that starts with 15 **and** are of length 5. But the second query always shows me no rows.

Why is that?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/468bc/1). Post your table definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case could be that the field is a large empty string? Such as `"15123         "`

You could also try another solution?

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where col1 like '15%' AND Len(col1)=5
```

EDIT - FOR FUTURE REFERENCE:

For sake of comprehensiveness, char and nchar uses the full field size, so char(10) would be `15________` ("15" + 8 characters) long, because it implicitly forces the size, whereas a varchar resizes based on what it is supplied `15` is simply `15`.

To get around this you could

A) Do an LTRIM/RTRIM To cut off all extra spaces

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where rtrim(ltrim(col1)) like '15___'
```

B) Do a LEFT() to only grab the left 5 characters

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where left(col1,5) like '15___'
```

C) Cast as a varchar, a rather sloppy approach

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where CAST(col1 AS Varchar(192)) like '15___'
```

Comment: Your question made me double-check the type. It's nchar not nvarchar. Hence it's not working. And I need to talk to some people about a change.

Comment: In the meantime you could go the dirty route and cast it as a varchar.

Comment: a side note: there is a variety of nasty "space" characters like Vertical Tab wich is CHAR(11) or Column Break which is CHAR(14). These look like a blank in SSMS editor, but the TRIMs don't catch them.

Answer (score 3):

Does this query return anything?

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where len(col1) = 5 and
      left(col1, 2) = '15';
```

If not, then there are no values that match that pattern.  And, my best guess would be spaces, in which case, this might work:

```
select id, col1, len(col1)
from tableA
where ltrim(rtrim(col1)) like '15___';
```